# Scale a piece of html with transform and correct the height

Tags: css

If you scale a piece of html, it does not affect the layout of the surrounding, as demonstrated in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/GRrNKWd).

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div>What comes after</div>
```

I'm wondering if there is a generic way to fix the layout height of the scaled html so that the next elements have the correct position and in particular do not overlap.

By generic, I mean it should be a solution that is

- independent of the content of the scaled html - changing the content should just work,
- works with html content that relies on `px` and `rem` units and
- one that allows different scaling factors.

I suspect it's not possible (relative units such as 100% are relative to the element in `transform`s, but to the parent in `height`s), but I want to check with the experts.

The actual problem that triggered this question can be worked around in any case, but it would be more elegant if the workaround wasn't necessary.

Comment: You can use `font-size`! `.item { border: 1px solid #ccc; font-size: 35px; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
font-size: 200%;
```

Add this to `.item` will have the same result and fix your issue

Comment: I added the requirement for this to work with content using units other than `em` - otherwise there would be no need to use `transform` as `font-size` would do all the scaling. Sorry for the inaccurate question.

Comment: @John can you simply use `font-size: 2em;` instead? (if default font-size is 1em of course).